# c#: escape XML string and write to HTML

Tags: c#, html, xml

I am reading an XML file and I want to write the actual contents to HTML. I think the problem is that HtmlTextWriter is treating my XML tags as HTML tags. I have tried using HttpUtility.HtmlEncode/Decode and SecurityElement.Escape but these don't work. How do I escape the tags so that I get literal strings to write to my HTML page.

```
private string WriteXmlToHtml()
    {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string line;

            StreamReader file = new StreamReader("test.xml");

            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(line);
                //System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape
                writer.Write(line);
                counter++;
            }
        }

        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

//edit: I have shamelessy implemented Xanatos' `<pre>` tags into the output string. Source in the comments

```
writer.Write(String.Format("<pre>{0}</pre>",HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(line)));
```

produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Settings>
```

```
 <Code>D:picture\simple</Code>
```

...

plus it adds a line break after each line. Unfortunately it does not keep the indention.

This should get rendered as valid xml in your html file.

Comment: thanks for this. but i think im actually putting this on an HTML table with 2 columns. the 1st column would be the line number and the 2nd will contain the tag. do you have any idea how I could preserve the indentation of the XML?

Comment: @wintersolstice you can use the <pre> </pre> tags probably and put inside the xml.

Comment: @wintersolstice `writer.Write(String.Format("<pre>{0}</pre>",HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(line)));`

Comment: I have a perfectly indented xml with line numbers now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
private string WriteXmlToHtml()
{
    string filePath = @"d:\abc.xml";
    return Server.HtmlEncode(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
}
```